# How to create ad-hoc network from iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, networking

I'm looking for info on how to programmatically create an ad-hoc network from within an app on an iOS device. I've heard that this is possible in 4.3 with the hotspot feature but I'm not looking to tether.

I'm also open to options involving jailbreaking and private APIs on devices that don't support 4.3 (iPhone 3G).

Bluetooth is not an option for my usage.

Thanks

Comment: have you found a suitable solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on your carrier to allow this configuration or not.

If your carriers does allow, you could find it at

> Settings -> General -> Network ->
>   Personal Hotspot

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a programmatic way to create an ad-hoc network from within an app. I've edited my question for clarity.

Comment: As I see you are open to jailbreak options, so you should checkout MyWi http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-news/667531-mywi-released-turn-your-iphone-into-wifi-hotspot.html

Comment: UOW! I have just read the "within my app" text... Sorry, MyWi is not a solution in that case...